# How to get outside in new line or call new command after calling the command artisan tinker in laravel.

Tags: php, laravel

I have called the "php artisan tinker" command in command prompt then so i can execute the laravel php code but now how can call new command because every code is compiled because it understand this is the code of laravel.

I am new at command prompt and laravel so please help to solve this problem.

I have added here one screenshot so any one can understand what have done.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

try : exit , do your commands and access tinker again whenever you want

[image]

Comment: Actual ctrl+d is not work but the working key is "ctrl+z+x".

Comment: you are right , strange... it worked with me before , but exit works fine

Answer (score 0):

Actual **Ctrl+D** is not worked but actual working key is **Ctrl+z+x** then enter.

I have done this thing after using all key of alphabetic with ctrl button and i have got the success.

[image]